# Six term exact sequence In E-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

I just want to know whether the two six term exact sequences in E-theory is true for nonseparable C*-algebras. We know already if the first varible is complex number, then we get six term exact sequence in K-theory, which is true for any (nonseparable) C*-algebra. I expect that one varible can be nonseparable.

Thanks.

Comment: If $A$ satisfies the UCT (iff E-equivalent to an abelian C*-algebra) and has finitely generated K- thery, then the functor $E_G(A,-)$ will commutes with colimits. I think for such $A$ six-term exact sequences is true for nonseparable C*-algebras in second variable.